# PHPExcel in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

I'm trying to export my Webform settings to an Excel file by using the [PHPExcel module](http://drupal.org/project/phpexcel), but it looks like [it's documentation](http://drupal.org/node/1351450) isn't modified for Drupal 7...

When trying to define the two-dimensional array `$data[row][column]` (as mentioned in the API), I keep stumbling upon an errors...

I try to add "John Doe" in Cell A1, "john@example.com" in Cell B1, etc.

```
$data = array(
    1 => array(
        'A' => 'John Doe',
        'B' => 'john@example.com'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'A' => 'Jane Doe',
        'B' => 'jane@example.com'
    ),
  );
```

But nothing ends up in the Excel file. Sometimes the first letter, but nothing more...
What does this module require as `$data`?

Answer (score 2):

The data table shold look like this:

```
 $data = array
    (
        array("Volvo",22,18),
        array("BMW",15,13),
        array("Saab",5,2),
        array("Land Rover",17,15)
    );
```

And whole working example will look like this:

```
function hoook_export_excel() {
    module_load_include('inc', 'phpexcel');
    $data = array();
    $headers = array();
    // First worksheet
    // Get the nodes
    $data = array
    (
        array("Volvo",22,18),
        array("BMW",15,13),
        array("Saab",5,2),
        array("Land Rover",17,15)
    );

    $headers = array("CAR","COUNT1","COUNT2");

    // Store the file in sites/default/files
    $dir = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri('public://')->realpath();
    $filename = 'export1.xls';
    $path = "$dir/$filename";
    // Use the .xls format
    $options = array('format' => 'xls');
    $result = phpexcel_export($headers, $data, $path, $options);
    if ($result == PHPEXCEL_SUCCESS) {
        drupal_set_message(t("Ok"));
    }
    else {
        drupal_set_message(t("Error"), 'error');
    }
}
```

This will return Excel:
[image: and result:]

Answer (score 0):

[mbahojlo](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/26679/mbahojlo) already answers your question just fine. I just want to add, that it is fairly easy to create your own function to export Excel data. These are two functions (first one is a page callback) which I wrote for my module `webform_invitation`:

```
<?php
function webform_invitation_download_file($nid) {
  //this is the XLS header:
  $xlshead=pack("s*", 0x809, 0x8, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0);
  //this is the XLS footer:
  $xlsfoot=pack("s*", 0x0A, 0x00);

  $codes = db_select('webform_invitation_codes', 'c')
  ->fields('c')
  ->condition('nid', $nid, '=')
  ->execute();
  $node = node_load($nid);
  $data = "";
  $row = 0;
  while ($code = $codes->fetchAssoc()) {
    $data .= webform_invitation_xlsCell($row, 0, $code['code']);
    $row++;
  }
  $filename="codes-".$nid.".xls";
  header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
  header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
  header("Content-Type: application/download");;
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
  echo $xlshead . $data . $xlsfoot;
  exit; //this is  important!
}

function webform_invitation_xlsCell($row,$col,$val) {
  $len=strlen($val);
  return pack("s*",0x204,8+$len,$row,$col,0x0,$len).$val;
}
?>
```